# Angular filter catching values that contain the filter.. how to make it strict if strict doesn't work (as i expect)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to angular so please be gentle.

the problem:

i have a custom filter for a dropdown using ng-repeat on the options

```
<select ng-model="SelectPart">
    <option ng-repeat="part in parts| filter:customFunction" value="{{ part.id }}">{{ part.name }}</option>
</select>
```

here is the custom function (updated and tested):

```
$scope.customFunction = function(item){
    return item.ouder_lichaamsdeel_id === '2' || item.id === '2';
};
```

now here is my question:

It turns out the function is correct. the problem is with the next dropdown menu

```
<select ng-show="SelectPart">
    <option ng-repeat="subPart in subParts| filter:{subPart.parent_id: SelectPart} : strict" value="{{ subPart.id }}">{{ subPart.name}}</option> 
</select>
```

there is something wrong with the `filter` on the second select. likely that the filter checks if `{12: 2}` and it recognizes the `2` in the `12`..
even with the `strict` filter applied. it still shows the `subParts` that have `Parent_id = 12`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the true filter : it will check if values are equals

You can see it here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Here's an example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="message in messages | filter:{ receiver: username }:true">
                    <td>{{message.sender}}</td>
                    <td>{{message.time}}</td>
                    <td>{{message.body}}</td>
                </tr>
```

I Hope it may help you